# Read values into a shell variable from a pipe

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I am trying to get bash to process data from stdin that gets piped into, but no luck. What I mean is none of the following work:

```
echo "hello world" | test=($(< /dev/stdin)); echo test=$test
test=

echo "hello world" | read test; echo test=$test
test=

echo "hello world" | test=`cat`; echo test=$test
test=
```

where I want the output to be `test=hello world`. I've tried putting "" quotes around `"$test"` that doesn't work either.

Comment: Your example.. echo "hello world" | read test; echo test=$test worked fine for me.. result: test=hello world ; what environment are running this under? I'm using bash 4.2..

Comment: Do you want multiple lines in a single read? Your example only shows one line, but the problem description is unclear.

Comment: @alex.pilon, I'm running Bash version 4.2.25, and his example does not work for me too. May be that's a matter of a Bash runtime option or environment variable? I've the example does not work with Sh neither, so may be Bash can try to be compatible with Sh?

Comment: @Hibou57 - I tried this again in bash 4.3.25 and it no longer works. My memory is fuzzy on this and I'm not sure what I may have done to get it to work.

Comment: @Hibou57 @alex.pilon the last cmd in a pipe should affect the vars in bash4>=4.2 with `shopt -s lastpipe` -- http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html#LASTPIPEOPT

Comment: @alex.pilon the $test variable was probably already bound from a previous attempt. Repeating this with a fresh session will fail as expected.

Comment: We can use _mkfifo(1)_ to create a named pipe, say `/tmp/p` (mind the access rights). Redirect the data source to it, and leave the source to the background `echo "..." > /tmp/p &`. We would be blocked here waiting for consumption otherwise. Then redirect the input of `read` from the pipe, and stay with it (do not end with `&`). We stay because we are waiting for data, and because, with `&`, the receiving variable would be in a subprocess, invisible to the main one. This named pipe method works both interactively and in script, allows updates on the go, and is quite portable.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Use

```
IFS= read var << EOF
$(foo)
EOF
```

You *can* trick `read` into accepting from a pipe like this:

```
echo "hello world" | { read test; echo test=$test; }
```

or even write a function like this:

```
read_from_pipe() { read "$@" <&0; }
```

But there's no point - your variable assignments may not last! A pipeline may spawn a subshell, where the environment is inherited by value, not by reference. This is why `read` doesn't bother with input from a pipe - it's undefined.

FYI, http://www.etalabs.net/sh_tricks.html is a nifty collection of the cruft necessary to fight the oddities and incompatibilities of bourne shells, sh.

Comment: You can make the assignment last by doing this instead:    

      
    `test=``echo "hello world" | { read test; echo $test; }```

Comment: Let's try this again (apparently escaping backticks in this markup is fun):
`test=\`echo "hello world" | { read test; echo $test; }\``

Comment: can I ask why you used `{}` instead of `()` in grouping those two commands?

Comment: The trick is not in making `read` take input from the pipe, but in using the variable in the same shell that executes the `read`.

Comment: the extra `{ }` block trick won't be needed in bash4>=4.2 with `shopt -s lastpipe` -- http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html#LASTPIPEOPT

Comment: That works perfectly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980090/how-to-read-from-file-or-stdin-in-bash

Comment: Got `bash permission denied` when trying to use this solution. My case is quite different, but I couldn't find an answer for it anywhere, what worked for me was (a different example but similar usage): `pip install -U echo $(ls -t *.py | head -1)`. In case, someone ever has a similar problem and stumbles upon this answer like me.

Comment: This question does not address the OP question, shell parameters usable after the pipeline. Therefore, downvoting.

Comment: May I ask how to make the function `read_from_pipe` works? `printf '   xx  yy   zz   ' | read_from_pipe a b c` will not set the variables `a b c` in the parent shell.

Answer (score 131):

if you want to read in lots of data and work on each line separately you could use something like this:

```
cat myFile | while read x ; do echo $x ; done
```

if you want to split the lines up into multiple words you can use multiple variables in place of x like this:

```
cat myFile | while read x y ; do echo $y $x ; done
```

alternatively:

```
while read x y ; do echo $y $x ; done < myFile
```

But as soon as you start to want to do anything really clever with this sort of thing you're better going for some scripting language like perl where you could try something like this:

```
perl -ane 'print "$F[0]\n"' < myFile
```

There's a fairly steep learning curve with perl (or I guess any of these languages) but you'll find it a lot easier in the long run if you want to do anything but the simplest of scripts. I'd recommend the Perl Cookbook and, of course, The Perl Programming Language by Larry Wall et al.

Comment: "alternatively" is the correct way. No UUoC and no subshell. See [BashFAQ/024](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Answer (score 65):

This is another option

```
$ read test < <(echo hello world)

$ echo $test
hello world
```

Comment: The significant advantage that `<(..)` has over `$(..)` is that `<(..)` returns each line to the caller as soon as the command that it executes makes it available.  `$(..)`, however, waits for the command to complete and generate all of its output before it makes any output available to the caller.

Comment: This is called [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html). [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/) v1.7.4 uses it to generate passwords from `/dev/urandom`.

Answer (score 57):

`read` won't read from a pipe (or possibly the result is lost because the pipe creates a subshell). You can, however, use a here string in Bash:

```
$ read a b c <<< $(echo 1 2 3)
$ echo $a $b $c
1 2 3
```

But see @chepner's answer for information about `lastpipe`.

Comment: Nice and simple one-liner, easy to understand. This answer needs more upvotes.

Comment: `<<<` adds line feed which may be not desired

Comment: @LoganMzz: True, but `read` consumes it because it's the default delimiter. As a result, the variable doesn't contain it. Note for comparison that this also does not result in the variable containing a newline even though `echo` outputs one: `d=$(echo "foo")` because command substitution removes trailing newlines.

Answer (score 49):

I'm no expert in Bash, but I wonder why this hasn't been proposed:

```
stdin=$(cat)

echo "$stdin"
```

One-liner proof that it works for me:

```
$ fortune | eval 'stdin=$(cat); echo "$stdin"'
```

Comment: That's probably because "read" is a bash command, and cat is a separate binary that will be launched in a subprocess, so it's less efficient.

Comment: sometimes simplicity and clarity trump efficiency :)

Comment: definitely the most straight-forward answer

Comment: The problem I ran in to with this is that if a pipe isn't used, the script hangs.

Comment: @DaleA Well, of course. Any program that tries to read from standard input will "hang" if nothing is fed to it.

Comment: @djanowski but it's not necessarily the expected behaviour of a given script. If only there was a way to handle the absence of stdin gracefully, and fall back to 'regular' behaviour if it's not present. [This](http://superuser.com/a/747905/34981) post almost has it - it accepts either arguments or stdin. The only thing missing is being able to provide a usage helper if neither are present.

Comment: Thanks, this answer in my opinion is the best. Fixed my issue.

Comment: Simple and elegant solution.

Comment: While searching for alternatives to the accepted answer, I decided to go with something similar to this answer for my use case :)  ```${@:-$(cat)}```

Comment: I am sorry, it was my mistake. Wish I could change my vote.

Answer (score 33):

`bash` 4.2 introduces the `lastpipe` option, which allows your code to work as written, by executing the last command in a pipeline in the current shell, rather than a subshell.

```
shopt -s lastpipe
echo "hello world" | read test; echo test=$test
```

Comment: ah! so good, this. if testing in an interactive shell, also: "set +m" (not required in an .sh script)

Comment: This is a long standing peeve for me.. You can add `shopt -s lastpipe` and `set +m` (or `set -o monitor`) to ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_aliases, but the is a bug that `set +m` wont stick. I found a workaround by adding it to the `export PROMPT_COMMAND='set +m` (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1395963/bash-set-m-option-does-not-work-when-placed-in-the-bashrc-file)

Answer (score 26):

A smart script that can both read data from PIPE and command line arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -p /dev/stdin ]]
    then
    PIPE=$(cat -)
    echo "PIPE=$PIPE"
fi
echo "ARGS=$@"
```

**Output:**

```
$ bash test arg1 arg2
ARGS=arg1 arg2

$ echo pipe_data1 | bash test arg1 arg2
PIPE=pipe_data1
ARGS=arg1 arg2
```

**Explanation:** When a script receives any data via pipe, then the /dev/stdin (or /proc/self/fd/0) will be a symlink to a pipe.

```
/proc/self/fd/0 -> pipe:[155938]
```

If not, it will point to the current terminal:

```
/proc/self/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/5
```

The bash `[[ -p` option can check it it is a pipe or not.

`cat -` reads the from `stdin`.

If we use `cat -` when there is no `stdin`, it will wait forever, that is why we put it inside the `if` condition.

Comment: You can also use `/dev/stdin` which is a link to `/proc/self/fd/0`

Answer (score 16):

The syntax for an implicit pipe from a shell command into a bash variable is

```
var=$(command)
```

or

```
var=`command`
```

In your examples, you are piping data to an assignment statement, which does not expect any input.

Comment: Because $() can be nested easily. Think in JAVA_DIR=$(dirname $(readlink -f $(which java))), and try it with `. You will need to escape three times!

Answer (score 12):

In my eyes the best way to read from stdin in bash is the following one, which also lets you work on the lines before the input ends:

```
while read LINE; do
    echo $LINE
done < /dev/stdin
```

Comment: I almost went crazy before finding this. Thanks a lot for sharing!

Answer (score 10):

The first attempt was pretty close. This variation should work:

```
echo "hello world" | { test=$(< /dev/stdin); echo "test=$test"; };
```

and the output is:

> test=hello world

You need braces after the pipe to enclose the assignment to test and the echo.

Without the braces, the assignment to test (after the pipe) is in one shell, and the echo "test=$test" is in a separate shell which doesn't know about that assignment. That's why you were getting "test=" in the output instead of "test=hello world".

Comment: @KevinBuchs, the OP's question is how to get "bash to process data from stdin that gets piped into". And OP was on the right track, just missing the curly braces around the two shell commands. When you use a pipeline, the shell forks itself to execute each part, but since variable assignments are only for the current shell (or sub-processes if you export), when the sub-process exits the variable assignment is lost. The curly braces put the shell commands after the pipe into a single shell so the assignment is usable. Maybe you have a different question you want to ask?

Comment: You are right, my mistake. Sorry.

Comment: Best answer. Summarized in this short description: you have an [bash] array of data returned by some script and want to repeat the same action on each member of that array.

Wasted 1 hour solving this.

Answer (score 10):

Because I fall for it, I would like to drop a note.
I found this thread, because I have to rewrite an old sh script
to be POSIX compatible.
This basically means to circumvent the pipe/subshell problem introduced by POSIX by rewriting code like this:

```
some_command | read a b c
```

into:

```
read a b c << EOF
$(some_command)
EOF
```

And code like this:

```
some_command |
while read a b c; do
    # something
done
```

into:

```
while read a b c; do
    # something
done << EOF
$(some_command)
EOF
```

But the latter does not behave the same on empty input.
With the old notation the while loop is not entered on empty input,
but in POSIX notation it is!
I think it's due to the newline before EOF,
which cannot be ommitted.
The POSIX code which behaves more like the old notation
looks like this:

```
while read a b c; do
    case $a in ("") break; esac
    # something
done << EOF
$(some_command)
EOF
```

In most cases this should be good enough.
But unfortunately this still behaves not exactly like the old notation
if some_command prints an empty line.
In the old notation the while body is executed
and in POSIX notation we break in front of the body.

An approach to fix this might look like this:

```
while read a b c; do
    case $a in ("something_guaranteed_not_to_be_printed_by_some_command") break; esac
    # something
done << EOF
$(some_command)
echo "something_guaranteed_not_to_be_printed_by_some_command"
EOF
```

Comment: `[ -n "$a" ] || break` should also work – but the problem about missing actual empty lines remains

Answer (score 5):

Piping something into an expression involving an assignment doesn't behave like that.

Instead, try:

```
test=$(echo "hello world"); echo test=$test
```

Answer (score 4):

The following code:

```
echo "hello world" | ( test=($(< /dev/stdin)); echo test=$test )
```

will work too, but it will open another new sub-shell after the pipe, where

```
echo "hello world" | { test=($(< /dev/stdin)); echo test=$test; }
```

won't.

---

I had to disable job control to make use of [chepnars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19142644/3744681)' method (I was running this command from terminal):

```
set +m;shopt -s lastpipe
echo "hello world" | read test; echo test=$test
echo "hello world" | test="$(</dev/stdin)"; echo test=$test
```

[Bash Manual says](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin):

> lastpipe
>
> If set, and **job control is not active**, the shell runs the last command
>   of a pipeline not executed in the background in the current shell
>   environment.

Note: job control is turned off by default in a non-interactive shell and thus you don't need the `set +m` inside a script.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were trying to write a shell script which could take input from stdin.
but while you are trying it to do it inline, you got lost trying to create that test= variable.
I think it does not make much sense to do it inline, and that's why it does not work the way you expect.

I was trying to reduce

```
$( ... | head -n $X | tail -n 1 )
```

to get a specific line from various input.
so I could type...

```
cat program_file.c | line 34
```

so I need a small shell program able to read from stdin. like you do.

```
22:14 ~ $ cat ~/bin/line 
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then echo enter a line number to display; exit; fi
cat | head -n $1 | tail -n 1
22:16 ~ $
```

there you go.

Answer (score 1):

The questions is how to catch output from a command to save in variable(s) for use later in a script. I might repeat some earlier answers but I try to line up all the answers I can think up to compare and comment, so bear with me.

The intuitive construct

```
echo test | read x
echo x=$x
```

is valid in Korn shell because ksh have implemented that the last command in a piped series is part of the current shell ie. the previous pipe commands are subshells. In contrast other shells define all piped commands as subshells including the last.
This is the exact reason I prefer ksh.
But having to copy with other shells, bash f.ex., another construct must be used.

To catch 1 value this construct is viable:

```
x=$(echo test)
echo x=$x
```

But that only caters for 1 value to be collected for later use.

To catch more values this construct is useful and works in bash and ksh:

```
read x y <<< $(echo test again)
echo x=$x y=$y
```

There is a variant which I have noticed work in bash but not in ksh:

```
read x y < <(echo test again)
echo x=$x y=$y
```

The <<< $(...) is a here-document variant which gives all the meta handling of a standard command line. < <(...) is an input redirection of a file-substitution operator.

I use "<<< $(" in all my scripts now because it seems the most portable construct between shell variants. I have a tools set I carry around on jobs in any Unix flavor.

Of course there is the universally viable but crude solution:

```
command-1 | {command-2; echo "x=test; y=again" > file.tmp; chmod 700 file.tmp}
. ./file.tmp
rm file.tmp
echo x=$x y=$y
```

Comment: This is a very good explanatory answer but I can't seem to get the multiple-value construct working. The first variable gets populated by the first line of my command's output but the second one stays empty. Any idea where I could be going wrong?

Comment: @HashimAziz - you might want to include the shell code you were using so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something similar - a function that parses a string that can be passed as a parameter or piped.

I came up with a solution as below (works as `#!/bin/sh` and as `#!/bin/bash`)

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

my_func() {
    local content=""
    
    # if the first param is an empty string or is not set
    if [ -z ${1+x} ]; then
 
        # read content from a pipe if passed or from a user input if not passed
        while read line; do content="${content}$line"; done < /dev/stdin

    # first param was set (it may be an empty string)
    else
        content="$1"
    fi

    echo "Content: '$content'"; 
}


printf "0. $(my_func "")\n"
printf "1. $(my_func "one")\n"
printf "2. $(echo "two" | my_func)\n"
printf "3. $(my_func)\n"
printf "End\n"
```

Outputs:

```
0. Content: ''
1. Content: 'one'
2. Content: 'two'
typed text
3. Content: 'typed text'
End
```

For the last case (3.) you need to type, hit enter and CTRL+D to end the input.

Answer (score -3):

How about this:

```
echo "hello world" | echo test=$(cat)
```

Comment: Basically a dupe from my answer below.

Comment: Maybe, I would argue mine is slightly cleaner and closer to the code posted in the original question.

Comment: @KevinBuchs As far as I can tell, this doesn't assign any variables that persist after completion. Did you try it?

Comment: Please ignore my (now deleted) comment. I was mistaken.

Comment: This `echo`s an assignment (without actually escaping the content to be `eval`-safe), but it doesn't _perform_ an assignment in such a way as to make the variable available later in the script.