# How to read stdin when no arguments are passed?

Tags: bash, stdin

Script doesn't work when I want to use standard input when there are no arguments (files) passed. Is there any way how to use stdin instead of a file in this code?

I tried this:

```
if [ ! -n $1 ] # check if argument exists
   then
   $1=$(</dev/stdin)  # if not use stdin as an argument
   fi

var="$1"
while read line
   do
   ...                # find the longest line
   done <"$var"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash read from file or stdin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980090/bash-read-from-file-or-stdin)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just substitute bash's specially interpreted `/dev/stdin` as the filename:

```
VAR=$1
while read blah; do
  ...
done < "${VAR:-/dev/stdin}"
```

(Note that bash will actually use that special *file* `/dev/stdin` [if built for an OS that offers it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38580/7703), but since bash 2.04 will work around that file's absence on systems that do not support it.)

Answer (score 17):

For a general case of wanting to read a value from stdin when a parameter is missing, this will work.

```
$ echo param | script.sh
$ script.sh param
```

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -- "${1:-$(</dev/stdin)}" "${@:2}"

echo $1
```

Comment: I prefer this solution to the loop because you don't have to embed your logic inside any outer code.

Comment: `set -- ${@:-$(</dev/stdin)}` if you want read _all_ arguments from the positionals, stdin otherwise. (Like how `grep` behaves.)

Comment: Works! Can you explain what `"${@:2}"` is for?

Comment: Stolen from other answers - it expands to remaining parameters

Answer (score 6):

**[pilcrow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19619634/45375) provides an elegant solution**; this is an explanation of **why the OP's approach didn't work**.

The main **problem with the OP's approach** was the **attempt to *assign to* positional parameter `$1`** with `$1=...`, which won't work.

The LHS is expanded by the shell to the *value* of `$1`, and the *result* is interpreted as the name of the variable to assign to - clearly, not the intent.

The **only way to assign to `$1` in bash is via the `set` builtin**.
The caveat is that `set` invariably sets *all* positional parameters, so you have to include the other ones as well, if any.

```
set -- "${1:-/dev/stdin}" "${@:2}"     # "${@:2}" expands to all remaining parameters
```

(If you expect only at most *1* argument, `set -- "${1:-/dev/stdin}"` will do.)

<sup>The above also corrects a secondary problem with the OP's approach: the attempt to store the *contents* rather than the *filename* of stdin in `$1`, since `<` is used.</sup>

`${1:-/dev/stdin}` is an application of bash [*parameter expansion*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) that says: return the value of `$1`, unless `$1` is undefined (no argument was passed) or its value is the empty string (`""`or `''` was passed). The variation `${1-/dev/stdin}` (no `:`) would only return `/dev/stdin` if `$1` is *undefined* (if it contains *any* value, even the empty string, it would be returned).

If we put it all together:

```
# Default to filename '/dev/stdin' (stdin), if none was specified.
set -- "${1:-/dev/stdin}" "${@:2}"

while read -r line; do
   ...                # find the longest line
done < "$1"
```

---

But, of course, the much simpler approach would be to use `${1:-/dev/stdin}` as the filename directly:

```
while read -r line; do
   ...                # find the longest line
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

or, via an intermediate variable:

```
filename=${1:-/dev/stdin}
while read -r line; do
   ...                # find the longest line
done < "$filename"
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables are assigned a value by `Var=Value` and that variable is used by e.g. `echo $Var`. In your case, that would amount to

```
1=$(</dev/stdin)
```

when assigning the standard input. However, I do not think that variable names are allowed to start with a digit character. See the question [bash read from file or stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980090/bash-read-from-file-or-stdin) for ways to solve this.

Comment: Indeed: `1` is not a valid variable name in bash. Aside from that, the only way to assign values to the positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, ... is to use the `set` builtin (`set -- <valueFor$1> <valueFor$2> ...`).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version of script:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=${1--} # POSIX-compliant; ${1:--} can be used either.
while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < <(cat -- "$file")
```

If file is not present in the argument, read the from *standard input*.

See more examples: [How to read from file or stdin in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6980090/55075) at stackoverflow SE