# How do I echo "-e"?

Tags: string, bash, echo

I want to `echo` a string that might contain the **same parameters** as `echo`. How can I do it without modifying the string?

For instance:

```
$ var="-e something"
$ echo $var
something
```

... didn't print `-e`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A surprisingly deep question.  Since you tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), I'll assume you mean `bash`'s internal `echo` command, though the GNU coreutils' standalone `echo` command probably works similarly enough.

The gist of it is: if you *really* need to use `echo` (which would be surprising, but that's the way the question is written by now), it all depends on what exactly your string can contain.

### The easy case: `-e` plus non-empty string

In that case, all you need to do is quote the variable before passing it to `echo`.

```
$ var="-e something"
$ echo "$var"
-e something
```

If the string isn't eaxctly an `echo` option or combination, which includes any non-option suffix, it won't be recognized as such by `echo` and will be printed out.

### Harder: string can be `-e` only

If your case can reduce to just "-e", it gets trickier.  One way to do it would be:

```
$ echo -e '\055e'
-e
```

(escaping the dash so it doesn't get interpreted as an option but as on octal sequence)

That's rewriting the string.  It *can* be done automatically and non-destructively, so it feels acceptable:

```
$ var="-e something"
$ echo -e ${var/#-/\\055}
-e something
```

You noticed I'm actually using the `-e` option to interpret an octal sequence, so it won't work if you intended to `echo -E`.  It will work for other options, though.

### The right way

Seriously, you're not restricted to `echo`, are you?

```
printf '%s\n' "$var"
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer! I have a question: what's the difference between the two versions of echo that you mentioned? I'm on ubuntu. How do I launch them?

Comment: If you're under bash, plain `echo` will get you the shell builtin, and `/usr/bin/echo` will get you the independent one.  (There are other ways)  You can tell them apart with `--version`.

Comment: This answer ignores that even the bash built-in echo implementation isn't guaranteed to behave consistently. Compare its behavior with and without `shopt -s xpg_echo; set -o posix` (and note that the former -- making bash's `echo` POSIX-compliant when the shell is otherwise in POSIX mode -- can be enabled-by-default as a compile-time flag).

Comment: It sure does. In all blunt honesty, the question wouldn't warrant it.

Answer (score 3):

Quote it:

```
$ var="-e something"
$ echo "$var"
-e something
```

If what you want is to get `echo -e`'s behaviour (enable interpretation of backslash escapes), then you have to leave the `$var` reference without quotes:

```
$ var="hi\nho"
$ echo $var
hi
ho
```

Or use `eval`:

```
$ var="hi\nho"
$ eval echo \${var}
hi\nho

$ var="-e hi\nho"
$ eval echo \${var}
hi
ho
```

Comment: I'd be curious about how you'd use `eval` to echo only "-e".

Comment: @JB. I also was... and kept testing a little bit. Just updated to show it :)

Comment: But... that still doesn't print "-e"!

Comment: To write the `-e` I use the first solution. If want I want is the `echo -e` behaviour, I use `eval`. I don't know what is the real OP question, one or the other :)

Comment: *My* question would be: can you get `echo` to print the string "-e" and "-e" only?

Comment: JB: Why would it print `-e` if the variable contains `-e something` (or why would you want that)? Your question doesn't make sense (but I'm sure I misunderstand you ;-) ).

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth imagine the variable contains "-e" only, if that makes more sense to you.  As to why one would want that, all bets are off.

Comment: @JB Ah! You would use `printf` (see also [here (Application Usage)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/echo.html)).

Answer (score 3):

The proper bash way is to use `printf`:

```
printf "%s\n" "$var"
```

By the way, your `echo` didn't work because when you run:

```
var="-e something"
echo $var
```

(without quoting `$var`), `echo` will see two arguments: `-e` and `something`. Because when `echo` meets `-e` as its first argument, it considers it's an option (this is also true for `-n` and `-E`), and so processes it as such. If you had quoted `var`, as shown in other answers, it would have worked.

Answer (score 2):

Since we're using bash, another alternative to `echo` is to simply `cat` a ["here string"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings):

```
$ var="-e something"
$ cat <<< "$var"
-e something
$ var="-e"
$ cat <<< "$var"
-e
$
```

`printf`-based solutions will almost certainly be more portable though.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
$ env POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 echo -e
-e
```

> Due to shell aliases and built-in `echo` command, using an unadorned
>   `echo` interactively or in a script may get you different functionality
>   than that described here.  Invoke it via `env` (i.e., `env echo ...`)
>   to avoid interference from the shell.
>
> The environment variable `POSIXLY_CORRECT` was introduced to allow the user to force the standards-compliant behaviour. See: [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) at Wikipedia.

Or use `printf`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$var"
```

<sup>Source: [Why is bash swallowing -e in the front of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21151049/55075) at stackoverflow SE</sup>

Comment: Better written as: `env POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 echo -e`. This doesn't use the builtin command, but the external command. Since it's very likely at `/bin/echo`, you might as well just call it so: `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 /bin/echo -e`. But your `printf` solution is of course the best and the most portable.

Answer (score 1):

Use `printf` instead:

```
var="-e bla"
printf "%s\n" "$var"
```

Using just `echo "$var"` will still fail if `var` contains just a `-e` or similar.  If you need to be able to print that as well, use `printf`.

Comment: `bash` echo doesn't treat `--` specially; it just prints it as well.

Comment: I propose another version since I think it might be important to be able to print `-e` alone as well (which won't work with `echo` at all).

Comment: Yeah, I was going to post a `printf`-based answer as well. I think that's the best solution.