# Why is bash swallowing -e in the front of an array

Tags: bash

Given the following syntax:

```
x=(-a 2);echo "${x[@]}";x=(-e 2 -e); echo "${x[@]}"
```

Output:

```
-a 2
2 -e
```

Desired output

```
-a 2
-e 2 -e
```

Why is this happening? How do I fix?

Comment: `echo "${x[*]}"` (`${x[*]}` returns all the items as a single word, whereas `${x[@]}` returns each item as a separate word)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### tl;dr

```
printf "%s\n" "${x[*]}"
```

### Explanation

`echo` takes 3 options:

```
$ help echo
[…]
Options:
  -n    do not append a newline
  -e    enable interpretation of the following backslash escapes
  -E    explicitly suppress interpretation of backslash escapes
```

So if you run:

```
$ echo -n
$ echo -n -e
$ echo -n -e -E
```

You get nothing. Even if you put each option in quotes, it still looks the same to bash:

```
$ echo "-n"
$ echo "-n" "-e"
```

The last command runs `echo` with two arguments: `-n` and `-e`. Now contrast that with:

```
$ echo "-n -e"
-n -e
```

What we did was run `echo` with **a single argument**: `-n -e`. Since bash does not recognize the (combined) option `-n -e`, it finally echoes the single argument to the terminal like we want.

#### Applied to Arrays

In the second case, the array `x` begins with the element `-e`. After bash expands the array `${x[@]}`, you are effectively running:

```
$ echo "-e" "2" "-e"
2 -e
```

Since the first argument is `-e`, it is interpreted as an option (instead of echoed to the terminal), as we already saw.

Now contrast that with the other style of array expansion `${x[*]}`, which effectively does the following:

```
$ echo "-e 2 -e"
-e 2 -e
```

bash sees the single argument `-e 2 -e` — and since it does not recognize that as an option — it echoes the argument to the terminal.

Note that `${x[*]}` style expansion **is not safe in general**. Take the following example:

```
$ x=(-e)
$ echo "${x[*]}"
```

Nothing is printed even though we expected `-e` to be echoed. If you've been paying attention, you already know why this is the case.

#### Escaping

The solution is to escape any arguments to the `echo` command. Unfortunately, unlike other commands which offer some way to say, “hey! the following argument **is not to be interpreted as an option**” (typically a `--` argument), bash provides no such escaping mechanism for `echo`.

Fortunately there is the `printf` command, which provides a superset of the functionality that `echo` offers. Hence we arrive at the solution:

```
printf "%s\n" "${x[*]}"
```

Comment: +1. Too bad `echo` doesn't take `--`

Comment: +1 although it's actually even worse than this, because different implementations of the `echo` command behave differently. Some interpret `-option`s, some ignore `-option`s but interpret escape sequences in the string, some do both... if you want predictable results, just avoid `echo` and use `printf` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Nice one!
What is happening is the first `-e` is being interpreted as an option for echo (to enable escape sequences'
Usually, you'd do something like `echo -- "-e"`, and it should print simply `-e`, but echo is happy to behave differently, and simply prints out `-- -e` as a whole string.

> echo does not interpret -- to mean the end of options.

The solution to the problem could also be found in the man pages:

> Due to shell aliases and built-in `echo` command, using an unadorned
>   `echo` interactively or in a script may get you different functionality
>   than that described here.  Invoke it via `env` (i.e., `env echo ...`)
>   to avoid interference from the shell.

So something like this should work:

```
x=(-a 2);echo "${x[@]}";x=(-e 2 -e); env echo "${x[@]}"
```

Comment: that actually still fails :(

Comment: I don't know who vote it, but seems wrong solution, fail in cygwin and  Solaris

Comment: Hm, odd, I did try it out and it worked.. Must be something to do with  versions of sheells, echo...

Comment: @SamSaffron Oh, Try this: export POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 in your env, and then try the above

Answer (score 2):

[@MichaelKropat's answer gives sufficient explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21151208/2113226).

As an alternative to `echo` (and `printf`), `cat` and a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)  [here-string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) can be used:

```
$ x=(-a 2);cat <<< "${x[@]}";x=(-e 2 -e); cat <<< "${x[@]}"
-a 2
-e 2 -e
$
```