# bash: missing the first element of an array

Tags: arrays, bash, echo

When the first element of an array is '-n' or '-e', has strange behavior, looks like some times the first element is missing.

My script `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a arrayP=('-p' 'text')
echo "arrayP"
echo ${arrayP[@]}
echo "${arrayP[@]}"
echo "'${arrayP[@]}'"
echo " ${arrayP[@]}"

echo ""

declare -a arrayN=('-n' 'text')
echo "arrayN"
echo ${arrayN[@]}
echo "${arrayN[@]}"
echo "'${arrayN[@]}'"
echo " ${arrayN[@]}"

echo ""

declare -a arrayE=('-e' 'text')
echo "arrayE"
echo ${arrayE[@]}
echo "${arrayE[@]}"
echo "'${arrayE[@]}'"
echo " ${arrayE[@]}"
```

Execution results:

```
root@host:~# ./test.sh
arrayP:
-p text
-p text
'-p text'
 -p text

arrayN:
texttext'-n text'
 -n text

arrayE:
text
text
'-e text'
 -e text
root@host:~#
```

`arrayP` works as expected, but `arrayN` and `arrayE`, each one behaves in different way.

I'm guessing `-n`, `-e` and probably others, have special meaning in some way, I cold not find any related information.

I'm using `GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: did you try escaping, like 
`declare -a arrayN=('\-n' 'text')`? Also try `printf "%s\n" ${arrayN[@]}"`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter within quotes, takes literally as `\-n`

Comment: @shellter, for printf, you need `[*]`, otherwise each array element will print on a separate line.

Comment: Possible duplicate? [Why is bash swallowing -e in the front of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21150793/27581)

Comment: @glennjackman : yes, I thought the `"%s\n"` would provide a good debugging view of what is happening (but didn't have time to test it, hence a comment, rather than an answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-n` and `-e` are options for `echo`. `-n` makes it not print a newline while `-e` makes it interpret escape sequences. In some cases, when you expand the array, bash reads these as options to `echo`. Eg:

```
$ echo -n hello          # no newline
hello$ echo "-n hello"   # string "-n hello"
-n hello
$ echo -e "\n"           # extra newline


$ echo "-e \n"           # string "-e \n"
-e \n
```

`-E` will also give similar behaviour.

One alternative is to use `printf %s` as per Sir Athos's answer.

Comment: I'm new to bash, I didn't think `echo` could have options. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with `echo`, not with the array itself.
If you print the array as separate arguments, `-n` and `-e` will be interpreted by `echo` as options (print without newline, and print with special escape characters, respectively). See `man echo` for a more detailed explanation.

You could use something like `echo '' ${arrayN[@]}` to prevent that, but you'll end up with an additional space at the beginning of the line.

If you're not bound to using `echo`, you can print it correctly by using `cat <<<${arrayN[@]}` or `printf "%s\n" "${arrayN[*]}"`

Comment: This printf invocation is simpler: `printf "%s\n" "${array[*]}"`

Answer (score 2):

Also, note this interesting behaviour:

```
$ array=('-n' 'text')

$ echo "${array[@]}"      # array expands into individual elements
text                      # no newline

$ echo "${array[*]}"      # array printed as a single string.
-n text
```

From a bash prompt, type `help echo`. Would be nice for echo to have a `--` option...