# Is there a Bash equivalent to PowerShell's CmdLets, which act as a pipeline filter?

Tags: linux, bash, powershell, filter, pipeline

I have a program writing text outputs to STDOUT. I would like to filter and color these outputs. In PowerShell, I wrote a CmdLet, which parses text lines and emits them to the console and colors certain parts if needed. [Example](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/release/tools/precompile/precompile.psm1?ts=2#L937)

**In PowerShell I have such a function:**

```
function Write-ColoredProgLine
{ [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    $InputObject,

    [Parameter(Position=1)]
    [switch]$SuppressWarnings = $false,
    [Parameter(Position=2)]
    [string]$Indent = ""
  )

  begin
  { $ErrorRecordFound = $false  }

  process
  { if (-not $InputObject)
    { Write-Host "Empty pipeline!"  }
    elseif ($InputObject -is [string])
    { if ($InputObject.StartsWith("vlib "))
      { Write-Host "${Indent}$InputObject" -ForegroundColor Gray   }  }
      elseif ($InputObject.StartsWith("** Warning:") -and -not $SuppressWarnings)
      { Write-Host "${Indent}WARNING: " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Write-Host $InputObject.Substring(12)
      }
      elseif ($InputObject.StartsWith("** Error:") -and -not $SuppressWarnings)
      { $ErrorRecordFound += 1
        Write-Host "${Indent}WARNING: " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Write-Host $InputObject.Substring(12)
      }
    }
    else
    { Write-Host "Unsupported object in pipeline stream"   }
  }

  end
  { $ErrorRecordFound   }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$expr = "prog.exe -flag -param foo"
$errors = Invoke-Expression $expr | Write-ColoredProgLine $false "  "
```

---

How can I process such operations in Bash?

I need some kind of inner state in the filter script, so tools like [GRC](https://github.com/garabik/grc?ts=2) are not powerful enough.

Comment: Bash for windows, I assume? Entirely for entertainment as well?

Comment: Bash for Linux (Debian). Not for entertainment :). I need to support both platforms :).

Comment: Ah, so this is a question on porting to bash, gotcha!

Comment: PowerShell 6 runs on Linux. It is an open source project. While not ready for production, have you tried it? https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

Comment: Wow!!!. When did that happen? Last time I looked for PowerShell on Linux I found an old and outdated project with only a handful of CmdLets translating to standard Linux programs like `ps` pr `ls`. I'll definitively test it!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a POSIX compatible way to do that:

```
awk '
/vlib/ {
  $0 = "\33[1;36m" $0 "\33[m"
}
/warning/ {
  $0 = "\33[1;33m" $0 "\33[m"
}
1
'
```

Result:

> [image: console screenshot]

It should be noted that you cannot use [POSIX Sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) for this. While it is
tempting, POSIX Sed has no way to create the escape sequences needed here, while
[POSIX Awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) does.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sed` in your pipeline. Maybe it's not the easiest tool but very powerful. You can do pretty much with a substitution command:

```
echo test | sed -e 's/es/ES/'
```

output:

```
tESt
```

this could be used also for removing some patterns by substitution with nothing:

```
sed -e 's/pattern//'
```

and adding prefixes/suffixes to your patterns (& is your match):

```
sed -e 's/pattern/PREFIX&SUFFIX/'
```

For coloring syntax check this link:
http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php

But if you need keeping some inner state it will be easier to use `awk`

Comment: `sed` has no state. I need a state machine in the script to process chains of different text lines with markers. So there are begin markers, text, highlight markers, text and finally end markers.

Comment: Could I read from STDIN and write to STDOUT in a while loop and exit on EOF?

Comment: reading from stdin in bash scripts: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6980090/3722896, to write on standard output you can just use `echo`