# Why can't I pipe tail -f into my shell script?

Tags: shell, curl

Currently, I have a script (log.sh) that can pipe content to the REST API of a logging server as follows

```
curl -H "content-type:text/plain" -d $1 http://my-logging-server.com/api
```

Running ./log.sh "Hello world" works

But when I try to do a live tail and pipe the results into my shell script:

```
tail -f live.log | ./log.sh
```

I get:

```
curl: no URL specified!
```

Why doesn't curl recognise a URL?

Comment: `tail -f live.log | ./log.sh` doesn't set `$1` in your script. So `curl` sees `http://my-logging-server.com/api` as the argument to `-d` and then no URL argument.

Comment: to add to @lurker's correct assertion, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7045517/2186144 for handling $1 or stdin.