# Unexpected behavior when processing input via stdin but file input works fine

Tags: bash, shell

I have a program which transposes a matrix. It works properly when passed a file as a parameter, but it gives strange output when given input via `stdin`.

This works:

```
$ cat m1
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8

$ ./matrix transpose m1
1   5   
2   6   
3   7   
4   8
```

This doesn't:

```
$ cat m1 | ./matrix transpose
5
[newline]
[newline]
[newline]
```

This is the code I'm using to transpose the matrix:

```
function transpose {
    # Set file to be argument 1 or stdin 
    FILE="${1:-/dev/stdin}"
    if [[ $# -gt 1 ]]; then
        print_stderr "Too many arguments. Exiting."
        exit 1
    elif ! [[ -r $FILE ]]; then
        print_stderr "File not found. Exiting."
        exit 1
    else
        col=1
        read -r line < $FILE
        for num in $line; do
            cut -f$col $FILE | tr '\n' '\t'
            ((col++))
            echo
        done
        exit 0
    fi
}
```

And this code handles the argument passing:

```
# Main
COMMAND=$1
if func_exists $COMMAND; then
    $COMMAND "${@:2}"
else
    print_stderr "Command \"$COMMAND\" not found. Exiting."
    exit 1
fi
```

I'm aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980090/how-to-read-from-a-file-or-stdin-in-bash) but I can't figure out where I've gone wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for num in $line; do
    cut -f$col $FILE | tr '\n' '\t'
    ((col++))
    echo
done
```

This loop reads `$FILE` over and over, once for each column. That works fine for a file but isn't suitable for stdin, which is a stream of data that can only be read once.

A quick fix would be to read the file into memory and use `<<<` to pass it to `read` and `cut`.

```
matrix=$(< "$FILE")
read -r line <<< "$matrix"
for num in $line; do
    cut -f$col <<< "$matrix" | tr '\n' '\t'
    ((col++))
    echo
done
```

See [An efficient way to transpose a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729824/an-efficient-way-to-transpose-a-file-in-bash) for a variety of more efficient one-pass solutions.