# Bash Style to Receive input From Pipe

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I intend to execute this way:

```
./some_code | ./my_bash.sh
```

What is the syntax in `./my_bash.sh` so that it can take
input from other as pipe?

I tried this but wont work.

```
#!/bin/bash

# this is ./my_bash.sh
cut -f1 $@ | grep 'foo' | wc -l 
# $@ failed
```

Comment: except for the `@$` part, the code you have should work. However, you could write it as `cut -f1 | grep -c 'foo'`, or even just `grep -c $'^[^\t]*foo[^\t]*'`

Comment: See [reading values from a STDIN pipe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746553/bash-script-read-values-from-stdin-pipe)

Comment: @kojiro: You should post that as an answer, because it is one and deserves to be upvoted and credited as such.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you want the arguments (`$@`) to do. Perhaps just remove that part. Other than that the code you have should work. However, you could write it as `cut -f1 | grep -c 'foo'`, or even just `grep -c $'^[^\t]*foo[^\t]*'`.

Comment: To explain: basically, `cut` reads from standard input by default.  In your pipe-target script, the standard input of `cut` is the standard input of your script, which in turn is coming from the pipe, so that should work.

Comment: If you want the script to be able to take arguments for `cut` and pass them along as an additional feature, you can write it like so:
`cut -f1 "$@" | grep 'foo' | wc -l`.  The quotes around `$@` are magical, and in this specific usage what they do is tell bash to pass along *precisely* the arguments you got, with no re-splitting on spaces or other re-interpretations.