# dash redirect from stdin to stdout

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Key value of this question is related to use dash-symbol "-" to redirect stdin stream.

I have basic test script within next code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This causes the shell to await user input.
file -
# Need to emulate user input here...
```

Which one of shell-commands can emulate user input in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746553/bash-script-read-values-from-stdin-pipe
i think it includes an answer to your question

Comment: Are you asking about `bash` as in the shebang or `dash` as in the question title?

Comment: They are compatible in this particular aspect anyway; but then you should be asking generally about Bourne `sh` and compatibles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pipeline `cmd1 | cmd2` by definition connects the standard output file descriptor of `cmd1` as the standard input file descriptor of `cmd2`.

```
echo foo | file -
```

This particular example is hardly useful; the `file` command doesn't make a lot of sense to run on the kind of ephemeral data you have inside a pipeline. A more useful example runs `file` on, well, a file. If you absolutely want the file to be standard input, a simple input redirection does that.

```
file - </path/to/example/file
```

Or you might be looking for this:

```
file $(locate example/file)
```

where `locate` is an example of a command which prints the full path to a file you might want as the actual input argument to `file`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Both of your answers were helpful. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a [here document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents):

```
#!/bin/bash
# This causes the shell to await user input.
file - <<'EOF'
This is what the user
might have typed
if it wasn't in a here document.
${BASH:=head} $(ls | wc -l)
EOF
```

The here document continues up to the line containing only the marker word.
In the example, the marker word is EOF; you can choose any name you like (`!` is often used).  The quotes around the marker word mean that no shell expansion will be done on the here document, so the last line is not expanded by the shell.  If the quotes were missing from (as in `<<EOF`) then shell expansion occurs.  This is useful when you need it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was very helpful for me to understand input capabilities.