# Shell script for searching a string pattern in file name

Tags: shell

Hi i want to write a script that will go to a directory with many files and search a filename e.g. test_HTTP_abc.txt for this and search for *HTTP* string pattern, if it contains this string then set a variable equal to something:

something like:

var1=0

search  for 06
if it contains 06 then
var1=1
else
var1=0
end if

but in unix script . Thanks

Comment: This would better suit the SuperUser Q&A site.  But anyway, have you looked at `fgrep`?

Comment: What's the relationship betweem HTTP and 06? Are these fixed or something to use as a parameter? Do I understand correctly that you want to check all files whose name contains HTTP and return 1 if the file (not the file name) contains "06"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest thing is:

```
if test "${filename#*HTTP}" = "$filename"; then
  # the variable does not contain the string `HTTP`
  var=0
else
  var=1
fi
```

Some shells allow regex matches in `[[` comparisons, but it's not necessary to introduce that sort of non-portable code into your script.

Comment: If that's what the question means, how about `case $filename in *HTTP* ) var=1 ;; *) var=0 ;; esac` as the simplest thing?

Comment: @triplee I agree; a case statement is better.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
var=0
if fgrep -q 06 /path/to/dir/*HTTP*
then
    var=1
fi
```

`fgrep` will return 0 ("truth") if there is a match in one of the files, and non-true otherwise (including the case of no matching input files).

If you want a list of matching files, try `fgrep -l`.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I'm not going to write the script for you, you have to learn :)

Its easy if you break it down into smaller tasks;

The `ls` command is for looking at a directorie's contents. You can also use the `find` command to be a bit more intuitive, like `find /some/folder -name "*string*"`

To sift through the output of a command. You could store the output of a command to a [variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-bash-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command) or at using [pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746553/bash-script-read-values-from-stdin-pipe).

You can search this output with something like `awk` ([link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-scripting-using-awk/)), `grep` ([link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-in-bash/)) an so on.

Setting variables is easy also in bash; http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html

`foundit=1`

Why don't you have a go at trying to solve this puzzle first rather than someone telling you :D Show us where you get stuck in the puzzle.

Comment: -1 for the advice to use a Useless Use of `ls`. http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#ls

Comment: Why is that useless, you're going to try and tell me you never ever use `ls`, you know what is in every directory? How do we know this person even knows the `ls` command? So I'm mentioning it.

Comment: Because of http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and the frequent antipattern to use `ls *HTTP*` when all you need is `echo *HTTP*`

Comment: I didn't say he should be parsing the output of `ls`, just using it to look into directories; How is he going to know his script is working if he doesn't check with `ls`? I mentioned `find` for parsing output to/from (but that is for him to work out). Read before down voting.