# Write bash script that reads from pipe

Tags: bash

I'd like to do something like that:

```
cat file.txt | ./myscript.sh
```

file.txt

```
http://google.com
http://amazon.com
...
```

How can I read data in myscript.sh?

Answer (score 16):

You can do this with a `while loop` (process line by line), this is the usual way for this kind of things :

```
#!/bin/bash

while read a; do
    # something with "$a"
done
```

For further informations, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

---

If instead you'd like to *slurp* a whole file in a variable, try doing this :

```
#!/bin/bash

var="$(cat)"
echo "$var"
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash

var="$(</dev/stdin)"
echo "$var"
```

Comment: If your script simply holds a piece of a pipeline, e.g. a sed command, you can (after specifying the interpreter `#!/bin/bash`) just cat it: `cat|sed 's/abc/def/g'`

Answer (score 5):

You could use something like this:

```
while read line; do
  echo $line;
done
```

Read further here: [Bash script, read values from stdin pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746553/bash-script-read-values-from-stdin-pipe)

Answer (score 3):

You can trick `read` into accepting from a pipe like this:

```
echo "hello world" | { read test; echo test=$test; }
```

or even write a function like this:

```
read_from_pipe() { read "$@" <&0; }
```

Comment: This isn't "tricking" `read`. The problem is not reading from a pipe, it's that the variable that `read` sets is in a subshell, which goes away after the pipe completes.