# How to save specific command output to a variable in sh?

Tags: shell, sh

When I execute a specific command I obtain as output 2 values, like this:

```
2.056000 640.640015
```

I want to extract only the second value, and assign it to a variable, to use later.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a variable to contain the result of a command, `var=$(command)` is the solution.

In your case,

```
your_var=$(your_command | awk '{print $2}')
```

You have to perform the command and then pipe it to `awk`, that will get the second parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Fedorqui's approach is good, but for the sake of providing an alternative:

```
your_command | read DONT_CARE YOUR_VAR IGNORE_ANYTHING_TRAILING
```

This has the benefit of not needing to run up a subshell and awk.  Tested and working for zsh.  You don't have to bother with the IGNORE_ANYTHING_TRAILING, but then say your_command spat out 1 2 3 4, YOUR_VAR would end up with "2 3 4".

Comment: Good idea. Have to say that a basic `$ ls -l a | read p` did not work to me in bash. `$p` is not set.

Comment: Yeah... my old bash shell in cygwin is weird too: `echo 1 | read x` doesn't set x, `read -u 0 x` (descriptor for stdin) doesn't help, `cat | read x` doesn't work, but if I do just `read x` and type values it work's fine. Pipe's screwing it somehow. Some discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746553/bash-script-read-values-from-stdin-pipe - what a stupid shell! ;-P

Comment: Some shells (notably `bash`) will execute the `read` in a subshell, and so the variable is not available after the pipeline exits. The POSIX standard simply says that any or all commands in a pipeline may execute in a subshell; it does not require any specific behavior.