# bash way of setting multiple variables from a function

Tags: bash, function

I want to write a shell script in a more *top downish* design. I've use to do this with Kornshell scripts. I define various functions that may return multiple set of variables (for example, a `getopts` function). I can then use these functions in my main program to set the variables I want.

Unfortunately, BASH and Kornshell seem to diverge in the way they handle this instance. Here's a simple script I run in the Kornshell. My function `foo` returns four values. I'll read in these four values into variables in my main program:

```
#!/bin/ksh

function foo {
    echo "this:that:the:other"
}

IFS=":"
foo | read one two three four
echo "one = $one"
echo "two = $two"
echo "three = $three"
echo "four = $four"
```

This produces:

```
one = this
two = that
three = the
four = other
```

Works like a charm. Let's try the same program using BASH instead of Kornshell:

```
#!/bin/bash

function foo {
    echo "this:that:the:other"
}

IFS=":"
foo | read one two three four
echo "one = $one"
echo "two = $two"
echo "three = $three"
echo "four = $four"
```

This produces:

```
one = 
two = 
three = 
four =
```

The pipe to the read doesn't work at all. Let's try this as a *hereis* read:

```
#!/bin/bash

function foo {
    echo "this:that:the:other"
}

IFS=":"
read one two three four<<<$(foo)
echo "one = $one"
echo "two = $two"
echo "three = $three"
echo "four = $four"
```

I get:

```
one = this that the other
two =
three =
four =
```

That allowed `$one` to be set, but not the other variables. Strangely, the colons were removed from the string. Let's remove the colons from the return value:

```
#!/bin/bash

function foo {
    echo "this that the other"
}

read  one two three four<<<$(foo)
echo "one = $one"
echo "two = $two"
echo "three = $three"
echo "four = $four"

one = this
two = that
three = the
four = other
```

That does work. Each variable is read in from function `foo`.

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't setting `IFS` seem to work the way I would think it would in BASH? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to quote:

```
#!/bin/bash

function foo {
    echo "this:that:the:other"
}

IFS=":"
read one two three four<<<"$(foo)"
                          ^      ^
```

When executed it returns:

```
$ ./a
one = this
two = that
three = the
four = other
```

---

Regarding this one not working:

```
#!/bin/bash

...    

IFS=":"
foo | read one two three four
echo "one = $one"
```

I guess it is because `IFS` is defined in a different shell than the one having `read`. Also, to pipe `foo` to `read` doesn't seem to be the way to give a string to `read` in bash.

To do it, open a new shell, as seen on [Bash script, read values from stdin pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2746553/1983854):

```
$ foo | { IFS=":"; read one two three four; echo "one = $one"; echo "two = $two"; echo "three = $three"; echo "four = $four"; }
one = this
two = that
three = the
four = other
```

Comment: Yes. The quotes work. Thanks. I guess the pipe doesn't because the `read` and not the `IFS` are in a _subshell_. I hate that with BASH. I have the same issue with `while read` loops too where variables set in the loop are unset outside of the loop because the `while read` is a _subshell_. Works in Ksh, but not in BASH.

Comment: @DavidW. oh I was updating. See my recommended alternative, by opening the subshell as you say.

Comment: Keep in mind that there is also a bug in how `read` interacts with `IFS` that may apply here. It's been slated to be fixed in 4.3.

Answer (score 1):

Without using read this will also work in both `bash` and `ksh`:

```
IFS=: && set -- `foo`
echo "one = $1"
echo "two = $2"
echo "three = $3"
echo "four = $4"
```

bts This also works in BASH without creating a sub-shell:

```
function foo {
    echo "this:that:the:other"
}

IFS=":" read one two three four < <(foo)
echo "one = $one"
echo "two = $two"
echo "three = $three"
echo "four = $four"
```

Comment: The second one puts my whole program into a loop. I might be calling multiple functions and setting multiple variables.