# bash script not getting piped data

Tags: bash, pipe

I'm trying to write a bash script that will manipulate the data piped from xsel.

```
...
ary=()
while read data; do
    echo $data
    ary=( "${ary[@]}" "$data" )
done
```

The problem is there is nothing being read when I call:

```
xsel | myscript.sh
```

I have tried

```
echo "testing testing" | myscript.sh
```

and that works, and I also made sure there was something coming from xsel

```
xsel | festival --tts --pipe
# will read the clipboard string piped from xsel aloud
```

Any Suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash script, read values from stdin pipe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746553/bash-script-read-values-from-stdin-pipe)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`read` fails if it can't read a full line, and `xsel` doesn't output a line feed.

Replace your loop with:

```
readarray ary   # new in Bash 4
```

If you're only adding lines in an array as a proxy for sticking all the data in a variable, you can instead do:

```
input=$(cat)
```

Comment: You forgot to add `-t` to `readarray`. Also, using timeout (`-t`) for `read` could also be helpful.

Comment: `-t` strips trailing newlines, but the original problem seems to be that there is no trailing newline to strip.

Comment: @chepner If the OP actually expects data to be not multi-lined, then using a single `read` would be enough. `readarray` would not be needed.

Comment: By the way I'm not sure if your edit applies as it's not reading input from a file but from a command.