# GraphicsMagic : how to pipe filename to gm process from command line

Tags: graphicsmagick

```
echo file.jpg | gm convert @- -interlace Line -resize 300x300^\> - > /tmp/file_r.jpg
```

is not working..

but if i have file filename.txt with content as file.jpg

```
gm convert @filename.txt -interlace Line -resize 300x300^\> - > /tmp/file_r.jpg
```

works.

Any idea why

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
echo file.jpg | { read filename; gm convert "$filename" -interlace Line -resize 300x300^\> - > file_r.jpg; }
```

Mind the braces. More on reading variables from stdin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6779351/2659516).

Comment: I dont actually run this is shell. For me the gm processes is spawned already in nodejs. I can only communicate to it using streams. Because of some limits on the number of open file handlers, I don't want to stream the contents of the file to this process. So I was thinking of some ways of streaming the filename and make the gm process open and load the file..

Comment: It's hard to imagine what's going on there. Do you have any code sample/gist for that maybe?