# Assign variable in a pipleline

Tags: bash, command-line, zsh

I am trying to store `stdin` into a variable in a pipeline:

```
$ echo 'message' | variable="-" ; echo $variable
```

I know I can do a script for this; but I am just trying this way to understand.

Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746553/bash-script-read-values-from-stdin-pipe)

Comment: While many programs read from *stdin* when `-` instead of a filename is passed as an argument, this is by convention only. `-` is not the filename of *stdin*.

Comment: pipe defaultly runs under a subshell. i don't know why you are trying to do this, but your `variable` can't be reused.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that! Pipe runs in a sub shell that will not have the variable?

Comment: Well what I tried to do is quite weird, let me show it: I need to prefix a string before the output of the pipe, so was trying this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
echo 'message' | ( var="$(< /dev/stdin)"; echo "$var" )
```

Or:

```
echo 'message' | { var="$(< /dev/stdin)"; echo $var; }
```

Note: `( ... )` opens another new subshell after pipe.

---

Another way (using `lastpipe` bash`>=4.2`):

```
set +m;shopt -s lastpipe  # set +m disables job control
echo "hello world" | read test; echo test=$test
echo "hello world" | test="$(</dev/stdin)"; echo test=$test
```

[Bash Manual says](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin):

> lastpipe
>
> If set, and **job control is not active**, the shell runs the last command
>   of a pipeline not executed in the background in the current shell
>   environment.

Note that, job control is turned off by default in non-interactive shell.

Comment: pipe will open a new subshell anyways. unless `shopt -s lastpipe` is set. this is new after 4.2 though.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr yap, pipe opens one and `( )` another, but `{ }` doesn't open another. Nothing is changed though (in this case)