# Kubernetes: modify a secret using kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

How can I modify the values in a Kubernetes `secret` using `kubectl`?

I created the secret with `kubernetes create secret generic`, but there does not seem to be a way to modify a secret. For example, to add a new secret-value to it, or to change a secret-value in it.

I assume i can go 'low-level', and write the yaml-file and do a `kubectl edit` but I hope there is a simpler way.

(I'm using `kubernetes 1.2.x`)

Comment: https://github.com/rajatjindal/kubectl-modify-secret

Answer (score 65):

The most direct (and interactive) way should be to execute `kubectl edit secret <my secret>`. Run `kubectl get secrets` if you'd like to see the list of secrets managed by Kubernetes.

Comment: i'm sorry, just to clarify, your answer is "no there is no such way", right?

Comment: Sorry if I did not make myself clear enough: I am saying there _is_ a way by means of running the `kubectl edit` command I showed in my answer. To me, `kubectl` is a CLI (tool); if you were looking for something different, please let me know.

Comment: ... if you want to edit the base64 encoded data directly.

Comment: `echo -n "admin" | base64` and add the result to your .yaml file (command `kubectl edit`)

Comment: There is an easier way. Check out my answer.

Comment: Why does kubernetes impose this? Why is this base64 encoding necessary? For binary values it is needed to represent their value in text form, but I assume most secrets are ascii or utf8 text.

Answer (score 51):

In case you prefer a non-interactive update, this is one way of doing it:

```
kubectl get secret mysecret -o json | jq '.data["foo"]="YmFy"' | kubectl apply -f -
```

Note that `YmFy` is a base64-encoded `bar` string. If you want to pass the value as an argument, `jq` allows you to do that:

```
kubectl get secret mysecret -o json | jq --arg foo "$(echo bar | base64 -w 0)" '.data["foo"]=$foo' | kubectl apply -f -
```

I'm more comfortable using `jq` but `yq` should also do the job if you prefer yaml format.

Comment: without add newline after echo, add -n optin `kubectl get secret mysecret -o json | jq --arg foo "$(echo -n bar | base64)" '.data["foo"]=$foo' | kubectl apply -f -`

Comment: Here is one more variation: `kubectl get secret mysecret -o json | jq '.data."foo" |= ("bar" | @base64)' | kubectl apply -f -`

Comment: For long strings the `base64` command includes line breaks every 76 characters, which is breaking the decoding by k8s for long strings. I suggest adding `-w 0` to the end of it. So the final command is `kubectl get secret mysecret -o json | jq --arg foo "$(echo -n bar | base64 -w 0)" '.data["foo"]=$foo' | kubectl apply -f -` source: https://superuser.com/questions/1225134/why-does-the-base64-of-a-string-contain-n

Answer (score 37):

As I found myself in the need of modifying a secret, I landed up here.

Here is the most convenient way I found for editing a (one-line) secret.

This elaborates on `kubectl edit secret <my secret>` of Timo Reimann above.

`kubectl edit secret <my secret>` will (in my case) invoke vi.

Now I move the cursor to the space after the colon of the secret I want to edit.

Then I press `r` and `[enter]` which will put the base64 encoded value onto a line of its own.

Now I enter `:. ! base64 -D` which will decode the current line.

After making my changes to the value, I enter `:. ! base64` which will encode the changed value.

Pressing `k` `[shift]J` will rejoin the secret name and its new value.

`:wq` will write the new secretfile and quit vi.

**P.S.** If the secret has a multi-line value, switch on line numbers (`:set nu`) and, after changing the decoded value, use `A,B ! base64` where A and B are the line numbers of the first and last line of the value.

**P.P.S** I just learned the hard way that `base64` will receive the text to encode with an appended newline :( If this is no issue for your values - fine. Otherwise my current solution is to filter this out with: `.!perl -pe chomp | base64`

Comment: For re-encoding a multi-line secret, I suggest vim visual mode and `. ! base64 -w0`.

Answer (score 21):

Deriving from 'Skeeves' answer:

Base64 encode your value:
`echo -n 'encode_My_Password' | base64`
Open the secret in edit mode:
`kubectl edit secret my-secret`

The default editor will open, replace the value of an exiting key or add a new line and a new key with the encoded value.
Save and close the file. The updated value or new key-value pair has now been added to the secret.

Comment: Simple and easy. It was helpful.

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way from the command line:

```
echo "This is my secret that might go on multiple lines when encoded" | base64 -w 0 | read output;kubectl patch secret my_secret_name -p="{\"data\":{\"secret_key\": \"$output\"}}" -v=1
```

It will encode value `This is my secret that might go on multiple lines when encoded` and update your `my_secret_name` secret by adding `secret_key` key and encoded values as a last key-value pair in that secret.

Comment: like it but seem that the read part is not working: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2746553/1747983

Comment: this works for me: `read output < <(echo "My secret 1232" | base64);kubectl patch secret myKubeSecretName -p="{\"data\":{\"UserPassword\": \"$output\"}}" -v=1`

Comment: You can even directly use non-encoded value with `kubectl patch secrets my-secret -p='{"stringData":{"foo":"bar"}}'`

Answer (score 16):

I implemented a `kubectl` [plugin](https://github.com/rajatjindal/kubectl-modify-secret) just for this.

**To install using krew**

```
kubectl krew update
kubectl krew install modify-secret
```

**To run it**

```
kubectl modify-secret xyz -n kube-system
```

**Demo**

[image: using kubectl-modify-secret plugin]

Comment: Now this is a real answer!

Comment: Unfortunately doesnt work on win

Answer (score 12):

### The Easy Way : Delete and recreate the secret

After looking at all these answers, for my needs the best solution was to delete and recreate :

```sh
kubectl delete secret generic
kubectl create secret generic # or whatever ..
```

---

If you want to do it the hard way :

### Using `edit` to change a `docker-registry` secret

I came to this question looking to modify a "docker-registry" style secret.
Simply editing it using `kubectl edit secret` seemed fraught as I didn't know what the secret value looked like.

I had created it with a command like `kubectl create secret docker-registry generic-registry-secret --docker-server=docker.server --docker-username='my-cloud-usernname' --docker-password='my-auth-token' --docker-email='my@email.com'`

I could have edited it, I figured out after looking at the other various answers here how that could be done - I'm including my notes here in case they help others.

List secrets : `kubectl get secrets`
Details of specific secret : `kubectl describe secrets/generic-registry-secret`
Get value of secret : `kubectl get secret generic-registry-secret -o jsonpath={.data}`
Decode secret value : First get everything between "map[.dockerconfigjson:" and "]" and then do :
`echo "x9ey_the_secret_encoded_value_here_X0b3=" | base64 --decode`

I could then take from that the specific auth token value I was seeking, and replace it with a new one.  And then run that new full entire string through a `| base 64` to get the base 64 encoding, and now I could finally, confidently, change the value by using `kubectl edit secret generic-registry-secret` and put in the new correct value.

But a delete and recreate is the simpler option.

---

**References :**

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configmap-secret/managing-secret-using-kubectl/

Comment: Delete and recreate is the best way to go so far. Kudo for this answer !!!. Thanks @kris

Answer (score 5):

Add a new key to an existing secret.

```
kubectl patch secret $SECRET_NAME --type=json \
  -p='[{
    "op" : "add" ,
    "path" : "/data/'$KEY'" ,
    "value" : "'$(base64 <<< "$VALUE")'"
  }]'
```

Update an existing key in a secret

```
kubectl patch secret $SECRET_NAME --type=json \
  -p='[{
    "op" : "replace" ,
    "path" : "/data/'$KEY'" ,
    "value" : "'$(base64 <<< "$VALUE")'"
  }]'
```

I was only able to find the `replace` operation in documentation, with no mention of the `add` operation. However, it looked like it was [RFC 6902](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6902/) compliant, so I tested with `add` and it works fine. I would expect other operations defined by RFC 6902 to work as well, though I haven't tested them.

Answer (score 4):

#### Before editing secrets with kubectl...

**I would highly recommend on using** [k9s](https://github.com/derailed/k9s) (not only for this purpose, but also as a lightweight k8s CLI management tool).

As you can see below (ignore all white rectangles), when your cluster's context is set on terminal you just type `k9s` and you will hit a nice terminal where you can inspect all cluster resources.

Just type `":"` and enter the resource name (*secrets* in this case) which will appear in the middle of screen.

Then you can choose a secret with the up and down arrows and type `e` to edit it (green arrow):

[image]

Comment: OMG did not know this k9s feature!

Answer (score 4):

use [`stringData`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configmap-secret/managing-secret-using-config-file/#specify-unencoded-data-when-creating-a-secret) instead of `data` to specify unencoded data:

```
kubectl patch secret my_secret_name -p="{\"stringData\":{\"secret_key\": \"my secret\"}}"
```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way I found:

```
# You need a version of micro that includes this commit https://github.com/zyedidia/micro/commit/9e8d76f2fa91463be660737d1de3bff61258c90d
kubectl get secrets my-secret -o json | jq -r .data.config | base64 -d | micro | base64 -w 0 | xclip -selection clipboard && kubectl edit secrets my-secret
```

And using a bash function that you can put in your profile:

```
function ks-edit { kubectl -n $1 get secrets $2 -o json | jq -r '.data."'$3'"' | base64 -d | micro | base64 -w 0 | xclip -selection clipboard && kubectl -n $1 edit secrets $2; }
```

You can call it like this:

```
ks-edit <namespace> <secret> <key>
```

Comment: I don't think that someone want to install and use additional resources like micro :)

Comment: @Skrypter You have never used `micro`. :D

Answer (score 1):

Always get the copy of secrets before editing it -
`kubectl get secrets <your-secret-name> -n <namespace> -o yaml > mysecret.yaml`

Now you can edit run edit command to edit your secret -
`kubectl edit secrets <your-secret-name> -n <namespace>`

or you can make copy of your `mysecret.yaml` file & exit the secrets inside that & run -

`kubectl apply -f mysecret.yaml`

Make sure you are decoding & encoding with base64 for viewing & adding secrets respectively.

Answer (score 0):

By *far* the easiest way to do this is to mantain a local `.env` file for each of your secrets.

e.g

```
MY_SECRET=something
PASSWORD=anotherthing
```

Just run

```
kubectl create secret generic <name> --from-env-file=.env
```

And when you need to change it - just delete it and run the above command again.

No messing with `base64`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my one liner:

```
$ kubectl get secrets/my-secret -o yaml | yq '.dataStrings = (.data | map_values(@base64d)) | del(.data)' | vipe | yq '.data = (.dataStrings | map_values(@base64)) | del(.dataStrings)' | kubectl apply -f -
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you're wondering how to do this with `k9s`, I am adding here instructions on how to do this step by step:

1. Install krew from here https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user-guide/setup/install/ (skip this step in case you have already it)
2. Install modify-secret plugin:

   `kubectl krew install modify-secret`
3. Run the following command or add it to `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc`:

   `export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=~/`
4. Add the following to ~/k9s/plugin.yml

```
plugin:
  edit-secret:
    shortCut: Ctrl-X
    confirm: false
    description: "Edit Decoded Secret"
    scopes:
      - secrets
    command: kubectl
    background: false
    args:
      - modify-secret
      - --namespace
      - $NAMESPACE
      - --context
      - $CONTEXT
      - $NAME
```