# How to Refresh Worker Secrets Without Killing Deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-secrets, amazon-eks

I want to learn how to update secrets in worker pods without killing and recreating the deployment.

Currently pods pull in secrets to as env vars with:

```
        env:
        - name: SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: secret_access_key
              name: secrets
```

but this only happens when they startup.

So if there is a need to change a secret I have to:

1. Change the secret in `secrets.yaml`
2. `kubectl apply -f secrets.yaml`
3. `kubectl delete -f worker-deployment.yaml`
4. `kubectl apply -f worker-deployment.yaml`

I really don't like step 3 and 4 as they terminate jobs in progress.

What is a better workflow for updating env var secrets in place?

Comment: I found this really useful: https://github.com/stakater/Reloader

Answer (score 15):

There is no way to do a "hot reload" for pod's environment variables.

Although, you do not need to delete and recreate the deployment again to apply the new secret value. You only need to recreate the underlying pods. Some options are:

- `kubectl delete pods` to recreate them
- Editing some deployment trivial value to trigger a [Rolling Update](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment) (e.g., [changing the `terminationGracePeriodSeconds`](https://gist.github.com/jmound/ff6fa539385d1a057c82fa9fa739492e) from `30` to `31`).
- Use `kubectl rollout restart` to do a rolling restart on the deployment †

*† `rollout restart` is only available on kubernetes [v1.15+](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.15.md#cli-improvements)*

Comment: You could also add an annotation containing the checksum of the configmap, or the timestamp of its last modification. Slighly cleaner than abusing an unrelated filed in the template.

Comment: @PauloSchreiner on k8s v1.15 the `kubectl rollout restart` is a better option now to trigger the rolling update.

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned, what you want to do is not possible. However, there is an alternative offered by Kubernetes: mounting ConfigMaps as Volumes. For example

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: configmap-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test
      image: busybox
      volumeMounts:
        - name: config-vol
          mountPath: /etc/config
  volumes:
    - name: config-vol
      configMap:
        name: log-config
        items:
          - key: log_level
            path: log_level
```

In this case, the `log-config` `ConfigMap` would be mounted as a `Volume`, and you could access the contents from its `log_level` entry as the file “`/etc/config/log_level`” inside the pod.

Changes to the config map are reflected by changes in the files on the Volume, and those changes can, in turn, be watched by your application by using the appropriate functionality in your language.

Answer (score -6):

You are able to update secrets via a tool like K8S's WebUI (Dashboard) or fabric8 if you have the appropriate permissions.

Check out [Kubernetes modify a secret using the cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180209/kubernetes-modify-a-secret-using-the-cli) for other options.

Comment: The question is not about how to modify secrets (it's already done in step 1 and 2). It's about handling the reload of pod configs.

Comment: Curious why you thought I didn't understand the question. FWIW, I have personally used the Dashboard and Fabric8 to change the value of a secret which updated the corresponding environment value in the pod. If you are unaware of those options, I would be happy to demonstrate them for you.

Comment: Updating the corresponding environment without recreating the pods? Would be awesome to see this working! (Especially using the kubernetes dashboard). Can you create a POC to demonstrate it? Consider including the demonstration in [#24957](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24957) and [#22368](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22368), the people of Kubernetes project are unaware of this feature too.

Comment: I stand corrected. You can modify the secret values via the Dashboard and Fabric8; however, you must restart the pod(s) for any changes to be reflected in the environment. I appreciate the info Educardo.