# How to extract multiple environment variables from a regular expression in Bash?

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I essentially want to extract the parts from a URL into different environment variables for use later, so I am expecting to be able to do something like this:

```
echo "my-app.domain.com:8080" | \
sed -r 's/((\w+)\.)?(\w+\.\w+)(\:(\d+))?/\2\n\3\n\5/g' | \
read SUBDOMAIN DOMAIN PORT
```

However this does not seem to work (and for some reason the ":" from the port is always output in "\5"):

```
sh-4.2# echo "my-app.domain.com:8080" | \
sed -r 's/((\w+)\.)?(\w+\.\w+)(\:(\d+))?/\2\n\3\n\5/g'
my-app
domain.com
:8080
```

What is more strange to me is that if I print a new line after the \5, this will be the output:

```
sh-4.2# echo "my-app.domain.com:8080" | sed -r 's/((\w+)\.)?(\w+\.\w+)(\:(\d+))?/\2\n\3\n\5\n/g'
my-app
domain.com

:8080
```

In any case, when using read, none of the variables are set either... seems I am doing a number of things wrong but am unable to spot exactly what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU bash:

```
url="my-app.domain.com:8080"
[[ $url =~ ([^.]*)\.(.*):(.*) ]] 
subdomain="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
domain="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
port="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
echo "$subdomain $domain $port"
```

Output:

```
my-app domain.com 8080
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: That's... beautiful

Answer (score -1):

This is a duplicate, see [Bash script, read values from stdin pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746553/bash-script-read-values-from-stdin-pipe)
In particular, the bash built-in "shopt -s lastpipe" will cause the "read" command to be executed within this shell instead of a subshell.