# Bash : behaviors of the redirections

Tags: bash, io-redirection

## Question

Please confirm if my understandings are correct. Or correct if wrong and pointers to related technical article and documents would be appreciated.

---

These are doing the same.

1. `ls &>/tmp/01.log`
2. `ls 2>&1 >/tmp/02.log`
3. `ls > /tmp/03.log 2>&1`
4. `ls 2>&1 1>/tmp/04.log`

---

The result of 5 will be the same with 1 to 4 on a single core CPU where there will be no multiple execution threads in a process. If it could produce a different result, please help understand what is actually happening in each process and in the kernel.

For multi-core CPU environment, would it happen that while a thread on a core is writing to stdout, another thread on another core write to stderr and they could be interleaved?

5. `ls 1>/tmp/05.log 2>/tmp/05.log`

Below could cause errors e.g. stderr tries to write but stdout has not output anything yet.

```
ls 1>/tmp/05.log 2>>/tmp/05.log
```

---

The same with 1 to 4.

6. `ls 1<&2 > /tmp/06.log`

---

The result is the same with 1 to 4, although makes no sense of doing it.

7. `ls 2>&1 | cat<&0>&1 > /tmp/07.log`

---

## Researches

- [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: Chapter 20. I/O Redirection](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)
- [GNU Bash Reference Manual -3.6 Redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections)
- [Bash One-Liners Explained, Part III: All about redirections](https://catonmat.net/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three)
- [How could I remember how to use redirection?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/746/how-could-i-remember-how-to-use-redirection)
- [Read values into a shell variable from a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746553/read-values-into-a-shell-variable-from-a-pipe)

Answer (score 1):

Number 4 is different. Order matters: First FD 2 is redirected where FD 1 **currently** points to (by default the terminal, unless another redirection had been set up already in this process or by the parent process), and then FD 1 is redirected to the file.