# Why does the read command in bash work with a herestring but not with piped output?

Tags: bash, input, pipe, herestring

I'm trying to understand how the bash `read` command works under the hood.
Given that it expects its input to come from standard input, I was surprised to find out that piped input does not work as expected. E.g.

```
### Pipe scenario

echo "1 2 3" | read -r one two three
echo "one: $one, two: $two, three: $three"
# output:   'one: , two: , three:'
```

```
### Herestring scenario

read -r one two three <<< "1 2 3"
echo "one: $one, two: $two, three: $three"
# output:   'one: 1, two: 2, three: 3'
```

Can someone explain in what fundamental way do the above two ways of providing input differ from each other (from the point of view of the read command)?

---

<sub>**EDIT in response to comments:**</sub>

<sub>I do not want to know "how to work around passing input via a pipe", like the linked questions in the comments. I know how to do that (e.g. I can use a herestring!).


My question is, **what is the underlying mechanism that makes read behave differently in the two cases?**</sub>

Comment: Already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746553/read-values-into-a-shell-variable-from-a-pipe)

Comment: Hi @Ivan, please see edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `read` works, but you need to ask for the values in the same subshell:

```
echo "1 2 3" | (read -r one two three && echo "one: $one, two: $two, three: $three")
```

An alternative is

```
read -r one two three < <( echo "1 2 3")
```

Comment: And another alternative is disabling job control and enabling the lastpipe option

Comment: I think this kinda makes sense, but just to clarify. Are you saying that the difference between the two scenarios is that a pipe necessarily creates a new subshell and that the variables are actually bound in the subshell but then lost on return to the base shell?

Comment: Thank you, having experimented a bit more based on your suggestion, I now understand that pipes opening a subshell to process the piped command is exactly what happens. I am accepting this answer. Btw, regarding the 2nd snippet, I think this is closer to the pipe scenario: `echo "1 2 3" > >(read -r one two three && echo "one: $one, two: $two, three: $three")`. Similarly, I think the top example should be: `echo "1 2 3" | { read -r one two three && echo "one: $one, two: $two, three: $three" }`; piping into a subshell which immediately opens another subshell raises even more questions for me ...