# "read" command does not wok in /bin/sh script

Tags: shell, sh, posix, zsh, stdout

I need to read output of one command into variables. Here is simplified examle:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo AAA BBB | read X Y
echo $X
```

this echos empty string.

Whereas when i use /bin/zsh as shell, it works as expected.

Why does the read command not work in /bin/sh ?

Comment: Please see [BASH FAQ 24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: Chances are, the sh is forking the read statement, setting the variable in the newly created subshell, and then letting it die, leaving the variable unchanged in your upper level shell.

I'm not sure how to solve the problem in your shell, but there are ways.

In bash, I would change it to read x y < <(echo AAA BBB).

This syntax guarantees, that the echo will be the subshell, and the read in the main shell.

An interesting experiment for you would be to try this:

echo xxx yyy | sh -c 'read a b; echo a=$a b=$b;'

Comment: `echo AAA BBB | { read x y; echo "x: $x  y: $y"; }` ??

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746553/read-values-into-a-shell-variable-from-a-pipe) answer your question?

Comment: Your example doesn't work in zsh either. I think the problem is that if you have a pipe, `X|Y`, the command `Y` must be executed in a child process. Therefore, `read` has no chance to set any variable in the calling process.

Comment: You could use: `<<< "$(echo AAA BBB)" read X Y`, passing in a herestring.