Variable value lost in bash when input comes from a function
The following script mimics a problem I met in a larger script.
loop-break-example-functions.sh:
#!/bin/ksh
#!/bin/bash

function loop_function {
  echo_function | while read one two three
  do
  echo $one $two $three
    echo "in loop 1 onefound = $onefound"
    if [[ $two == "BB" ]]
    then
      onefound=$one
      echo "in loop in if onefound = $onefound"
      break
    fi
    echo "in loop 2 onefound = $onefound"
  done
  echo "end onefound = $onefound"
}
function echo_function {
  while read line
  do
    echo $line
  done <<EEE
  A B C
  AA BB CC
  AAA BBB CCC
EEE
}

loop_function

I works well in ksh but not in bash. When the shell is bash, the value of variable $onefound is lost in the end.
With ksh
# ./loop-break-example-functions.sh
A B C
in loop 1 onefound =
in loop 2 onefound =
AA BB CC
in loop 1 onefound =
in loop in if onefound = AA
end onefound = AA
#

Switching the 2 first lines to work with bash:
# ./loop-break-example-functions.sh
A B C
in loop 1 onefound =
in loop 2 onefound =
AA BB CC
in loop 1 onefound =
in loop in if onefound = AA
end onefound =
#

Can somebody explain the difference? How can I make it work in bash?
I tried giving onefound an initial value in the beginning of the function.
I saw that there is no problem when the input is more straighforward (not coming from a function). The following version is OK with both shells:
#!/bin/ksh
#!/bin/bash

function loop_function {
  while read one two three
  do
  echo $one $two $three
    echo "in loop 1 onefound = $onefound"
    if [[ $two == "BB" ]]
    then
      onefound=$one
      echo "in loop in if onefound = $onefound"
      break
    fi
    echo "in loop 2 onefound = $onefound"
  done <<EEE
  A B C
  AA BB CC
  AAA BBB CCC
EEE
  echo "end onefound = $onefound"
}

loop_function


It's not the function as such; it's the pipe. The last component in a pipe is executed in a subshell by default in bash and thus any variable setting or other changes are not available to the main shell subsequently. Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746553/read-values-into-a-shell-variable-from-a-pipe and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143958/in-bash-read-after-a-pipe-is-not-setting-values  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9954/why-is-my-variable-being-localized-in-one-while-read-loop-but-not-in-another

Not just the last component -- all pipeline components end up in individual subshells (by default). This is BashFAQ #24.

We would literally see about 90% fewer bash questions if the instructions from the [tag:bash] tag were enforced by the forum. Anyway, here it is again... "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here."
